# CORS configuration error with IIS express (from a fresh workstation install)

Tags: cors, iis-express

I moved in a new workstation and I have reinstalled IIS Express. Also, I have installed CORS module because my application is using .net 4.8 with Visual Studio 2019

But when I try to start the application, I am stuck in configuration errors, even if I have copied DLL and schema files in IIS Express files and default applicationhost.config

The strange thing is that if I remove the cors section in web.config file, I have a 500.60 CORS error, but when I insert the section in Web.config, I have 500.19 error

this is the section I use:

```
<cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
  <add origin="*">
    <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
    <allowMethods>
      <add method="GET" />
      <add method="POST" />
    </allowMethods>
  </add>
  <add origin="http://*" allowed="false" />
</cors>
```

Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: The [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) community would be better suited for a server configuration question

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the IIS CORS module to IIS Express, and the steps are not trivial.

But [I wrote about that](https://halfblood.pro/how-to-install-microsoft-cors-module-for-iis-express-7ac24e4c3bc4) and made a few PowerShell scripts to help.

Comment: "_I have installed CORS module_"

Comment: @starball if you verify what I meant exactly, you will see that CORS module wasn’t installed for IIS Express. 500.19 is clearly the proof.